# Could someone explain the bold sentence in simple words?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> **We need not be surprised that standing as it did further from the support of written records than the legends of Western Iran**, this
>   oral tradition could have given rise to a few false affiliations and
>   chronological anomalies. (Bivar, A. D. H., 1981. *Gondophares and
>   Shāhnāma*, p150)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is comparing an oral tradition to legends of Western Iran.

"This oral tradition" was not supported by written records("stood further from them"); the legends of Western Iran, in contrast, were more supported by such written records. Therefore, it is not surprising that the oral tradition might have given rise to some inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

I would, instead, say: "It is not surprising that this oral tradition, with fewer historical written records to support it than similar legends from western Iran, could have given rise ..."

The meaning is:

1) certain "legends of Western Iran" are (somewhat, partially) supported / confirmed by the written historical record (from Iran or other countries) and therefore, their historical "facts" / dates are not generally contested / debated (at least in comparison to the oral tradition).

2) "this oral tradition" (i.e., not the legends of western Iran, but hopefully more context is given in a previous sentence or paragraph) has less corroborating evidence ("standing as it did further away from", though this is not how I would say it) - e.g., fewer written historical documents (than the legends from Western Iran).

3) Because there is less evidence, one would expect (I would say "It is not surprising that" instead of "We need not be surprised that") that the dates / facts in the oral tradition are less likely to be accurate or precise, and that if there is any disparity, the legends with corroborating evidence should likely be believed more.